# How to match multiple characters in a regular expression?

Tags: regex

I have the string

```
7,456.23%
```

where I would like to use a regular expression to match BOTH the comma(,) and percent(%) characters and remove them so the result is

```
7456.23
```

I can figure out how to match one character or the other, but not both.

Answer (score 2):

Simply use [Character Classes or Character Sets](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html)

> With a "character class", also called "character set", you can tell the regex engine to match only one out of several characters.

Simply place the characters you want to match between square brackets. If you want to match an `a` or an `e`, use `[ae]`.

```
System.out.println("7,456.23%".replaceAll("[,%]",""));
```

OR try with ORing ([Alternation Operator](http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html))

```
System.out.println("7,456.23%".replaceAll(",|%",""));
```

Comment: Does a class not match only one character or the other? I want to match both characters and replace them.

Comment: have you tried the code. what `replace**All**()` does?

Comment: What language is used in your example? Do you have a Javascript example? Thanks.

Comment: @ChrisP It's Java language. In JavaScript you can try `"7,456.23%".replace(/[,%]/g,"")`